# validation on exact length of numeric field in laravel 5

Tags: laravel, laravel-4, laravel-5

I have numeric field i want to validate on exact fill 4 digits.

like: 1234, 4567,1245

but these invalid inputs:
like: 123, 346, 45m6, 34567

what I am trying:

```
'last4digits'             => 'numeric|between:4,4',
```

Answer (score 22, accepted):

You are looking for the `digits` rule. [From the docs](http://laravel.com/docs/5.0/validation#rule-digits):

> The field under validation must be numeric and must have an exact length of value.

```
'last4digits' => 'digits:4'
```

Answer (score 13):

in general case ,say, for a string with arbitrary characters:

```
'last_not_only_4_digits' => 'size:4'
```